# Queries with PDO and DBLIB driver to a SQL Server Database with Linked Servers

Tags: php, pdo, linked-server, sqlsrv

I´m using PDO and dblib driver to do queries in a external-application SQL Server database. Everything has worked fine so far with normal sentences. The question is than in this database engine, we have two 'linked servers', so that we can query databases of both servers without having to make a specific connection to a server:

```html
SELECT * FROM [TITAN\SERVER1].SERVER1.DBO.TIPOLICENCIA
```

These types of queries are supported and work correctly using a PDO type connection with sqlsrv, just as I have it in my local development environment:

```html
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$server; Database=$name", $user, $pass);//Local
```

... but this doesn't work in production environment (hosting), where our provider force us to use DBLIB extension with PDO:

```html
$conn = new PDO("dblib:version=7.0;charset=UTF-8;host=$server;dbname=$name", "$user","$pass");
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: none, simply this type queries do not return results. Queries to main server work normally.